# Qunit data erased

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

Can someone explain why in the third console log the data is empty?

This is a shortened version of a problem I'm having with my tests. I'm noticing the absence of data in my test functions, inserted in "QUnit.test (...)". Some of the functions, triggered by events, use this data and errors are occurring.

An executable code can be found on [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/gufaqujaju/edit?html,js,console,output)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").data("thedata", 1);
  console.log("First", $("p").data());
});

QUnit.config.autostart = false;
setTimeout(function() {
  QUnit.start();
  console.log("Second", $("p").data());
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Third", $("p").data());
}, 2000);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.1.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, but your HTML document is not valid (not sure that's the issue though). Those `link` and `script` tags should be in the `<head>` tag within your HTML doc.

Comment: That's right, but it's not the problem. I think writing that way becomes more obvious the part of code that matters, does not it?

Comment: Regardless, I cannot replicate this issue.

Comment: Okay. Corrected. I could not make it work on the snippet, so I included a JsBin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after seeing your JSBin I figured out what the issue is. Part of this is that in your code above you are not actually using QUnit at all (there are no tests), but the real issue is that the QUnit "fixtures" are reset after each test (intentionally). The first two work because QUnit must be considering that the first test, but the 2000 ms timeout for the third console log must happen after the "test", meaning the fixture is reset to its original HTML. Note that your add the data in JS, NOT in the HTML.

So... here are your options: put the data in the actual HTML (`<p data-thedata='1'>content</p>`) or you can set up a proper QUnit test with a `beforeEach` hook (this is my preferred option). Here is the code for option two, and a [working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gugoqezuku/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("First", $("p").data());
});

QUnit.config.autostart = false;

QUnit.module('data', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    $("p").data("thedata", 1);
    console.log("before each", $("p").data());
  }
});

QUnit.test('data delay', function(assert) {
  let done = assert.async();

  setTimeout(function() {  
    console.log("Second", $("p").data());
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Third", $("p").data());
    assert.ok($("p").data());
    assert.equal($("p").data().thedata, 1);
    done();
  }, 2000);
});

QUnit.start();
```

Comment: That's exactly it. With your answer I remade my search in the documentation and found where it is described (https://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#keeping-tests-atomic). Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If this did solve your issue you could accept the answer. ;)